# Android Java Object/Class Syntax Use In This Example

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android,  but I know `Javascript` so I have some familiarity in Object Oriented programming.

In this line:

```
Resources myResources = getResources();
AnimationDrawable androidAnimation;
androidAnimation = 
  (AnimationDrawable)myResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.frame_by_frame);
```

1. is androidAnimation a new object initialized by the
   AnimationDrawable class?
2. In (AnimationDrawable)myResources what is this syntax where the
   class is in parentheses proceeding a object?

Answer (score 2):

1. No. `androidAnimation` is not an object. It is a reference which points to an instance of `AnimationDrawable` class.

   In the following `object creation` statement and assigment: -

   ```
   MyClass obj = new MyClass();
   ```

   - Value on RHS - `new MyClass()` creates an `object`.
   - Value on LHS - `MyClass obj` creates a reference to that object.
2. This is called `typecasting`. This is done because, the `reference type` returned by that method invocation might not be compatible with the `reference type on LHS`. So, a typecast is needed to make it compatible.

For more details about these concepts, refer to [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html): -

- [Section # 4.3. - Reference Types and Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3)
- [Section # 5.  - Conversion and
  Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)
- [Oracle Tutorial - Classes and Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)